# Tangent Bundle of reducible genus one curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, genus

I need to know what can be said in general about the tangent bundle of reducible curves over complex numbers with arithmetic genus one, say $I_N$.

As far as I know for any Simpson semistable torsion free sheaf of rank one, the restriction over each component of $I_N$ must be $O_C(1)$, $O_C(0)$ or $O_C(-1)$ (where $C$ is a component which is actually a rational curve), and the (Jordan Holder) graded object must be $\oplus_i^N O_{C_i}(-1)$.

So I want to know whether this is true for the tangent bundle?

Tangent bundle, in this case, is stable or strictly semistable?

And if it's semi-stable can we actually determine the restriction over each component?

Comment: Your interpretation of the description of Simpson semistable torsion free sheaves of rank one seems strange --- if one twists such a sheaf by a line bundle, the degrees of the restriction might become more or less arbitrary.

Comment: Sorry, I had to mention, the polarized degree is zero, and by rank one, I mean restriction of the sheaf over each irreducible component is rank one...